# Delete previous circle before drawing new ones on the map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, geometry

I have this method:

```
  public void crowdArea(){

    for (int n=0; n<place.length; n++) {
        Location locationFromDB2 = new Location("");
        locationFromDB2.setLatitude(latt2[n]);
        locationFromDB2.setLongitude(longg2[n]);
        total = 0;
        double c [][]=new double[100][2];
        double p [][]=new double[100][2];

        for (int n2 = 0; n2 < latt.length; n2++) {
            Location locationFromDB3 = new Location("");
            locationFromDB3.setLatitude(latt[n2]);
            locationFromDB3.setLongitude(longg[n2]);
            float dist = locationFromDB2.distanceTo(locationFromDB3);

            if (dist < 500f) {
                c [total][0]=latt[n2];
                c [total][1]=longg[n2];

                p [total][0]=prelatt[n2];
                p [total][1]=prelongg[n2];

                total++;
            }
        }
        if (total >= 5) {
            draw(latt2[n], longg2[n]);
            state[n]="yes";
            boolean b=bearing2(c,p);
            Log.d("diriction is: ", b+"");
        }
        else{
            state[n]="no";

            // draw2(latt2[n], longg2[n]);

        }
    }
}

public void draw(double lat, double lonng){
    Circle myCircle;
    LatLng lt=new LatLng(lat, lonng);
    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
            .center(lt)   //set center
            .radius(500)   //set radius in meters
            .fillColor(0x40ff0000) //default
            .strokeColor(Color.RED)
            .strokeWidth(5);
    myCircle = map.addCircle(circleOptions);
}
```

which draws a circle on my map. 
this method is called every 15 secs, but it draws a circle on the previous circle and so on. what I want is to remove previous circles before adding the new one.

how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map.clear()` to clear the map before drawing the new circle.

Alternatively, if you have drawn other objects on the map and you don't want to delete them, just your previous Circle, you can do:

```
private Circle myCircle;

// ...

public void draw(double lat, double lonng){
    LatLng lt=new LatLng(lat, lonng);
    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
            .center(lt)   //set center
            .radius(500)   //set radius in meters
            .fillColor(0x40ff0000) //default
            .strokeColor(Color.RED)
            .strokeWidth(5);
    if (myCircle != null) {
        myCircle.remove();
    }
    myCircle = map.addCircle(circleOptions);
}
```

FOLLOWUP based on your code update:

```
private List<Circle> circles = new ArrayList<>();

public void crowdArea(){
    clearCircles();

    for (int n=0; n<place.length; n++) {
        Location locationFromDB2 = new Location("");
        locationFromDB2.setLatitude(latt2[n]);
        locationFromDB2.setLongitude(longg2[n]);
        total = 0;
        double c [][]=new double[100][2];
        double p [][]=new double[100][2];

        for (int n2 = 0; n2 < latt.length; n2++) {
            Location locationFromDB3 = new Location("");
            locationFromDB3.setLatitude(latt[n2]);
            locationFromDB3.setLongitude(longg[n2]);
            float dist = locationFromDB2.distanceTo(locationFromDB3);

            if (dist < 500f) {
                c [total][0]=latt[n2];
                c [total][1]=longg[n2];

                p [total][0]=prelatt[n2];
                p [total][1]=prelongg[n2];

                total++;
            }
        }
        if (total >= 5) {
            draw(latt2[n], longg2[n]);
            state[n]="yes";
            boolean b=bearing2(c,p);
            Log.d("diriction is: ", b+"");
        }
        else{
            state[n]="no";

            // draw2(latt2[n], longg2[n]);

        }
    }
}

public void draw(double lat, double lonng){
    LatLng lt=new LatLng(lat, lonng);
    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
            .center(lt)   //set center
            .radius(500)   //set radius in meters
            .fillColor(0x40ff0000) //default
            .strokeColor(Color.RED)
            .strokeWidth(5);
    circles.add(map.addCircle(circleOptions));
}

private void clearCircles() {
    for (Circle circle : circles) {
        circle.remove();
    }
    circles.clear();
}
```

Comment: is there is a way to keep markers and only remove circles?

Comment: ok, it works fine. but i'm drawing multiple circles each time the method is called, using this will only keep one circle. can you please check my code I updated it.

Comment: Then you need to use a `List`. Check my update and let me know if this works for you

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use

```
if(mapCircle!=null){
      mapCircle.remove();
    }
```

instead of `map.clear()` because this will remove every objects on the map

Comment: where should ii place this code? inside the method?

Comment: Convert your local variable myCircle into a field, and then yes put it at the begining of your method

Comment: worked fine, but this keeps only one circle. while the method is called more than once every 15 secs and draw multiple circles. can you please check my code I updated it. I want to keep the last multiple drawn circles.

Comment: I don't understand, you said you wanted to  >  remove previous circles before adding the new one

Comment: sorry for my poor explanation, I meant that the method is called multiple times each 15  secs and draw multiple circles and I want to keep all the circle from last 15 secs. anyways I got the answer. but I really appreciate your help! THANKS ALOT!!

Comment: @LamaTat , if David's answer is also helpful, consider upvoting it

Comment: @Antonio it is really helpful !! but unfortunately I cannot up vote until I have 15 reputations :(