# How to clear previously drawn circle in Google map Android?

Tags: android, dictionary, geolocation

I want the previously drawn circle to be removed. When I am searching for a new place, the first circle remains there and the new circle is also drawn. Basically every time when the location gets changed, circle keeps getting drawn(overlapping each other) without deleting the previous circle.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_geocoding_maps);

    toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.mapToolbar);if (!checkPlayServices()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Device not compatible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
    Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras==null)
    {
        itemAction=-1;
        Log.w(TAG, "Extras are null");
        finish();
    }
    else
    {
        try{
            item=extras.getParcelable(GeofenceUtils.P_KEY);
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.w(GeofenceUtils.getTag(), e.getMessage());
        }
        if (item != null) {
            if(item.getLatitude()==0.0&&item.getLongitude()==0.0) {
                //New item
                itemAction=0;
            }
            else {
                //Update item
                Log.w(TAG, "Title : "+item.getTitle());
                itemAction=1;
            }
            Log.w(TAG, "Item Action: "+itemAction);
        }
        else {
            Log.w(TAG, "Item null: ");
        }
    }
    dbHelper=GeofenceDBHelper.getInstance(this);
    assert toolbar != null;
    toolbar.setTitle("Pick a location");
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    address="";
    addressText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressText);
    if(itemAction==1) {
        address=item.getAddress();
        if (addressText != null) {
            addressText.setText(address);
        }
    }
    addressText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                Log.w(TAG, "onEditorAction");
                address = addressText.getText().toString();
                LatLng latLng = getLocationFromAddress(GeocodingMapsActivity.this, address);
                if (latLng != null) {

                    mlatitude = latLng.latitude;
                    mlongitude = latLng.longitude;

                    marker.setPosition(latLng);//match this behavior to your 'Send' (or Confirm) button
                    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 18);
                    mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);



                    circle = drawCircle(new LatLng(mlatitude, mlongitude));


                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "onEditorAction: address null");

                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    if(savedInstanceState!=null)
    {
        //For handling screen rotations
        mlatitude=savedInstanceState.getDouble("Latitude");
        mlongitude=savedInstanceState.getDouble("Longitude");

        Log.w(TAG, "itemAction savedInstanceState: "+itemAction);
    }
    else
    {
        mlatitude=item.getLatitude();
        mlongitude=item.getLongitude();
    }

    clearButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.clear_text);
    clearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addressText.setText("");
        }
    });

    MyLocationButton=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
    MyLocationButton.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE));
    MyLocationButton.setRippleColor(Color.parseColor("#f5f5f5"));
    MyLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                LatLng latLng = getCurrentLocation();
                if (latLng != null) {
                    setAddress();
                    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 18);
                    mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                  //  circle = drawCircle(new LatLng(mlatitude, mlongitude));


                }

            }
        }
    });
    MyLocationButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mGeofenceList=new ArrayList<>();
    buildGoogleApiClient();
    createLocationRequest();
    buildLocationSettingsRequest();
    checkLocationSettings();
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    Log.w(TAG, "onCreate");
}




private void removeEverything(){
    marker.remove();
    marker = null;
    circle.remove();
    circle = null;


}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */

Circle circle;
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Log.w(TAG, "onMapReady1");
    mMap = googleMap;
  //  mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    enableMyLocation();
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            marker.setPosition(latLng);
            mlatitude=latLng.latitude;
            mlongitude=latLng.longitude;
            setAddress();
        }
    });
    Log.w(TAG, "onMapReady2");
    LatLng mLocation=null;
    if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()&&itemAction==0)
        mLocation = getCurrentLocation();
    Log.w(TAG, "onMapReady3");
    if (itemAction==0&&mLocation != null) {
        mlatitude = mLocation.latitude;
        mlongitude = mLocation.longitude;
    }
    else if(itemAction==1) {
        mLocation=new LatLng(mlatitude, mlongitude);
    }
    else
        mLocation = new LatLng(0.0, 0.0);

    Log.w(TAG, "onMapReady3");
    if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
        setAddress();
    Log.w(TAG, "onMapReady4");





    marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mLocation).draggable(true));
    Log.w(GeofenceUtils.getTag(), item.getMarkerColor()+"");
   marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(GeofenceUtils.getMarker(item.getMarkerColor())));
    mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
    if(itemAction==1)
    {
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate=CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(item.getLatitude(), item.getLongitude()), 18);
        CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mLocation, 18);
        mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
      //  circle = drawCircle(new LatLng(mlatitude, mlongitude));

    }
    Log.w(TAG, "onMapReady5");




}
private Circle drawCircle(LatLng latLng) {

    CircleOptions options = new CircleOptions()
            .center(latLng)
            .radius(50)

            .strokeColor(Color.BLACK)
            .fillColor(Color.rgb( 229, 204, 229))

            .strokeWidth(3);



    return mMap.addCircle(options);
}
```

[There are two circles drawn, i want first circle to be removed as soon as the second circle is drawn.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GIVs.png)

Comment: I tried with this option, it's working for me. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36821142/delete-previous-circle-before-drawing-new-ones-on-the-map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36821142/delete-previous-circle-before-drawing-new-ones-on-the-map)

Comment: thankyou, it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Circle circle;
```

Before drawing a circle to the map. Check first if circle is drawn. Just remove the circle then draw new circle to the map.

```
 if(circle!=null){
      circle.remove();
    }
circle = drawCircle(new LatLng(mlatitude, mlongitude));
```